# Should we say one swims in the sea or on the sea? Also, the birds live in the tree or on the tree?

Tags: prepositions

I have these questions about prepostions. 
1. One is swimming in or on the sea?
2. The birds live in or on the tree.

Answer (score 2):

[In general, **on** means "on the surface of".  **In** means something more like "inside".](http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/prepositions-on-at-in.aspx)

So it would be more correct and idiomatic to say that you are swimming *in* the sea, because you are immersed in it, not on top of the surface of it, and the birds live *in* the tree, because they are all throughout the tree, not just on the surface of it.

Comment: As opposed to "a bird *on* the branch" or " a ship *on* the sea".