# Do we say "the flowers are on the tree" or "the flowers are in the tree"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

[image]

It seems that some flowers are on the tree and we can see them obviously but some other flowers are in the tree if they have hidden themselves somewhere under the leaves and branches.

This is what I guess.

Do we say "**the flowers are on the tree**" or "**the flowers are in the tree**"?

[This stackexchange link says](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105691/should-we-say-one-swims-in-the-sea-or-on-the-sea-also-the-birds-live-in-the-tr) "**the birds live in the tree, because they are all throughout the tree, not just on the surface of it.**".

Why don't we apply that kind of expression to some flowers "**in the tree**"?

It is difficult to see them because they **are surrounded** by leaves and branches?

Comment: If I were, I would say, "...flowers of the tree"

Answer (score 1):

On.

"In" would be used only for something physically inside the tree itself.  A bird's nest built on branches would be "on"; one built in a hollow would be "in."

Comment: On the other hand, a bird could be in the tree, when it was sitting on a branch.